# Puppet Partition Table

Tags: unix, module, puppet

I am creating a module to create and manage filesystems. I have everything working from physical volumes to mounting the filesystem. I am utilizing a puppetforge module called [LVM](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/lvm).

This module works great except for the fact that it does not manage the partition table at all. If you do a `pvcreate` with this module (or as a standalone command) you can create a physical volume without partitioning a disk. This does work however if you do an `fdisk -l` you will see that there are no partitions on that disk (because none were created). I would like to somehow manage partitions so that it provides more clarity on what that disk is being used for.

**Is there a puppet module/command/function that I can use to help manage partitions?** I created an exec that will do it but it feels "dirty" and I feel like there are cleaner solutions.

thanks,

My disk partitioner for reference:

```
#Where ${disk} is sdb1, sdc1, etc.

disks.each |$disk| {
  exec { "part_${disk}":
    command => "/usr/sbin/parted -a optimal -- /dev/${disk} unit compact mkpart primary \"1\" \"-1\" ; /bin/sleep 1",
    unless  => "/sbin/fdisk -l | grep /dev/${disk}",
  }
}
```

Comment: Partitions are the one type the LVM module does not handle. You will have to use an `exec` for those but not for the others. You can always create your own custom type and PR it to the LVM module.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Looking at the custom types.. I see you can create them and define properties but were is the code that performs those operations? For example how would puppet know to check the partition table for my partitions if th ensure flag was set?

Comment: You would need to write provider code for that.